# Pivotal Tracker - how do I move a story from one app to another

Tags: project-management

We have several Pivotal Tracker projects.

I entered a ticket in the wrong one.

How do I move it to the right one?

Answer (score 2):

To move a story, or a group of stories:

Select them first, using the selection check boxes to the right of story titles.

Then, select the 'Move to Project...' option in the Stories drop-down menu, and choose the project to which you'd like the story or stories moved.